# Making zend EmailAddress form validator return only one custom error message

Tags: php, zend-framework, validation

I'm creating an email form element like so (inside a Zend Form):

```
//create e-mail element
$email = $this->createElement('text', 'username')
              ->setLabel('E-mail:')
              ->setRequired(true)
              ->addFilters(array('StringTrim', 'StringToLower'))
              ->addValidator('EmailAddress', false, array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        Zend_Validate_EmailAddress::INVALID => 'Dit e-mail adres is ongeldig.',
                    )
              ));
//add element
$this->addElement($email);
```

Now, when an invalid e-mail is entered quite a lot of messages appear:

```
'#' is no valid hostname for email address '@#$@#'
'#' does not match the expected structure for a DNS hostname
'#' does not appear to be a valid local network name
'@#$' can not be matched against dot-atom format
'@#$' can not be matched against quoted-string format
'@#$' is no valid local part for email address '@#$@#'
```

I wonder, is it possible to make it only emit the error message provided by me, such as 'Please enter a valid e-mail address.'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way is to use [`addErrorMessage()`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/_Form_Element.html#Zend_Form_Element%3a%3aaddErrorMessage%28%29) to set a single custom message for all errors.

In your example you can add it to your code and call it fluently, or add the line

```
$email->addErrorMessage('Dit e-mail adres is ongeldig.');
```

You should also change the second parameter to addValidator as below, so that once validation has failed other conditions aren't checked.

```
->addValidator('EmailAddress', true)
```

It is explained in the [Reference Guide](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.form.elements.html#zend.form.elements.validators.errors) but not very well. The name `addErrorMessage` doesn't imply that it will override the default messages, but there you are.

Comment: Thanks. If I set the second parameter to true, what message should I set? The general INVALID one?

Comment: I would do. I don't think I've ever found it useful to show the user why their email address didn't validate. I usually just say 'Please enter a valid email address' or similar.

Comment: I understand. My question was more like "what if an other message fires, rather than the INVALID one?". In that case it will stop at the first invalid message and not show my custom message?

Comment: I believe it will always show your message. If that's not the case (and it should be easy enough to test) then I would just override all of the error messages with your own string.

Comment: The problem with the addErrorMessage method is that it will wipe out any other custom validator messages you have created for that element. For example, if you have a db lookup in a registration form to see if that email address already exists you will want that error to display rather than a default invalid email error. I found the only way around this is to overwrite the default email validator messages in the bootstrap and break the validator chain on failure.

Answer (score 1):

You could use either :

```
$email->addErrorMessage('Dit e-mail adres is ongeldig.');

$email->addValidator('EmailAddress', true);
```

Or you can use :

```
$email_validate = new Zend_Validate_EmailAddress();

$email_validate->setMessage("Your custom message");

$email->addValidator($email_validate ,TRUE);
```